# Find a closed form for $10 + 16 + 22 + … + (6n-2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Question: find a closed form for $10 + 16 + 22 + … + (6n-2)$

My attempt: I have put the summation in sigma notation: $∑^n_{k=2}(6k-2)$

I don't have much experience doing this, where would I go from here?

Comment: Do you know what $\sum_{k=2}^n k$ is? do you

Comment: There's an easy closed form for sum of k up to n, try to reach that!

Comment: @LouisPan I know that that sum is n(n+1)/2, and I'm pretty sure I'm meant to transform the summation into something where I can apply that formula, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: $6\sum_{k=2}^{n} k - 2\sum_{k=2}^{n} 1$

Comment: @jem if you're not sure how to approach this with sum manipulation, try Gauss's method!

Comment: @jemdo Subtracting one term leads to the desired formula.

Comment: @jemdo The sum is actually $n(n+1)/2-1$, since the summation is from $k=2$, not $k=1$. To evaluate the sum, use linearity of the sum as DecarbonatedOdes did.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good start to have the summation notation. To proceed, observe that

$$
\sum_{k=2}^n (6k-2)=6\sum_{k=2}^n k-\sum_{k=2}^n 2\tag{1}
$$

Now to break things down, you need to find
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n2,\quad \sum_{k=2}^nk\tag{2}
$$
The first one is easy. To find the second one, notice that
$$
\sum_{k=2}^nk=(\sum_{k=1}^nk)-1
$$
Then you can apply the formula you know about $\sum_{k=1}^nk$.

---

[Added another perspective mentioned in [Bernard's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4295712/find-a-closed-form-for-10-16-22-6n-2/4295719#comment8945375_4295719).]

The above is one way to do this problem if you wanted to reduce your problem to something you know, i.e., the formula for $\sum_{k=1}^nk$.

Alternatively, if you know what an [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) is, you could calculate the sum directly by
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n(6k-2)=\frac{(n-1)(10+6n-2)}{2}\;.
$$

Comment: @LouisPan: There's a brave anonymous troll  on this site which loves downvoting. This being said, you might simplify a bit mentioning the sum of consecutive terms in an arithmetic sequence is the arithmetic mean of the first and last terms, times the number of terms

Comment: @Bernard: I don't know why my previous comment was deleted. But I consider you made a good point and I have added it into my answer.